# how to deal with multiple values for a single field in table?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

i have 1 table in phpmyadmin `users` which contains below fields.

`users`:

### uid | name | contact.no

There can be more then one contact number for a single user.
One way to solve it is using one more table for contact number and pass its primary key to `users` table.
Is there any other way other then this one.
Can we implement array structure in `contact.no` field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put commas over there and save multiple numbers but then it kills the whole concept of an `RDMS` and `Normalization`. That will not be a good database design. So it is advisable to normalize your table and not store such multiple information in one field. Database doesn't really stress itself if you have 1 more table.

A very well written explanation can be found [Here on Microsoft Website](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283878)

Comment: I have lots of other fields for `users` table which will have more then 1 data for 1 name. If i am creating 1 more table then it will be headache while fetch data from multiple tables.

Comment: You don't have to create 1 more table for every new field. Unless all those fields are unrelated and can be in different multiples.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't have to create multiple tables for each type of entry, just a more robust table structure. Make sure that the information that needs to be normalized is in a consistent format.

**Users:**
uid | name | username

```
1,Bob,bcratchet
```

**Info:**
iid | itype | icontent | uid

```
1,cell,000.000.0000
2,home,000.000.0000    
3,home_addr,1234 Anystreet, anytown USA
4,work_addr,4567 Anystreet, anytown USA
```

select * from Users u,Info i where u.uid=i.uid and name="Bob";

Pull it into a multidimensional array in any application and you're good to go.

*edit******
Ideally it would go further and show a table like itypes where you would further normalize the types like so:

**itypes:** itype_id | itype

```
1,cell
2,home
3,home_addr
4,work_addr
```

Then in the Info table it would say "itype_id" instead of "itype."